# Remove current object from array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am looping through an array with the following code:

```
for leftBlock in leftBlocks {
    // ...
}
```

I'm doing some comparisons inside of that for-loop, and in some cases I need to remove the current leftBlock from the array. I know how to remove if I have the index, but in this case, I don't.

How do I delete the current object from the array?

Comment: Use either `find` or `filter`

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` function which returns a tuple for each value in the array:

```
for (index,leftBlock) in enumerate(leftBlocks.copy()) {

}
```

Now you can remove object by its index from original array `leftBlocks`.

Comment: Is it safe to modify an Array that is bring enumerated in Swift?

Comment: @Zaph, thanks, forgot to write copy() for original array. Of course, it is impossible to change array being enumerated.

Comment: It is possible but perhaps not safe in Swift, I'm not sure about safe.

Comment: @Zaph, obviously it is not a good scheme to implement. The main goal of my post was to show how one can get index in for-in iteration.